# Using Bree with NX monorepo and typescript

Tags: typescript, nrwl-nx

I'd like to run Bree as part of a monorepo. Eventually this application should be able to be ran in a Docker container. I've setup Bree as an application (`apps/application`), in which I would like to load a library (`libs/lib`). In the root of the application (`index.ts`) this library is available, but it isn't found in `jobs/job.ts`. My guess is that it has something to do with the workers that Bree uses, but I haven't found anything related to my problem.

The error I get when I run `nx serve application` is:

```
Worker for job "job" had an error {
  err: [worker eval]:2
      console.log((0, lib_1.lib)());
                      ^
  
  ReferenceError: lib_1 is not defined
```

I've setup a [demo repository](https://github.com/ashwinvandijk/nx-bree-typescript), but I'll also post some relevant files here:

`app/apps/project.json`:

```
{
  "root": "apps/application",
  "sourceRoot": "apps/application/src",
  "projectType": "application",
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/node:build",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/apps/application",
        "main": "apps/application/src/index.ts",
        "tsConfig": "apps/application/tsconfig.app.json"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        {
          "target": "build",
          "projects": "dependencies"
        }
      ]
    },
    "serve": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/node:execute",
      "options": {
        "buildTarget": "application:build"
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],
      "options": {
        "lintFilePatterns": ["apps/application/**/*.ts"]
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
      "outputs": ["coverage/apps/application"],
      "options": {
        "jestConfig": "apps/application/jest.config.js",
        "passWithNoTests": true
      }
    }
  },
  "tags": []
}
```

`app/application/src/index.ts`

```
import Bree from 'bree';
import { lib } from '@nx-bree-typescript/lib';

import { job } from './jobs/job';

console.log(lib()); // <--- works

const bree = new Bree({
  root: false,
  jobs: [job],
});

bree.start();
```

`apps/application/jobs/job.ts`

```
import { lib } from '@nx-bree-typescript/lib';

export const job = () => {
  console.log(lib()); // doesn't work
};
```